# NHibernate Criteria left antijoin/ subquery confusion

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I'll preface this with the fact that NHibernate is well out of my comfort zone, so this may be much simpler than I'm making it out to be.

I have a `users` table and an `events` table mapped to `user` and `event` objects.

My `event` objects reference a singular `user` object.

I have a property that I persist on my `user` object for *LastActivityTimeStamp*.

I have properties on my `event` object related to *EventType* and *Success*.

To determine a list of users that are "online", I need to collect all user objects with a *LastActivityTimeStamp* greater than a previously calculated `cutoff` value, whose last activity in the `events` table was not a successful "Logoff" event type.

How would I write this criteria?

Comment: No takers?  I wouldn't have thought this to be that difficult to answer for someone in the know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to tweak this

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Event>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Success", true))
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("User.Id", "u.id"))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("TimeStamp"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("EventType"))
    .SetMaxResults(1);

session.CreateCriteria<User>("u")
    .Add(Restrictions.Ge("LastActivityTimeStamp", cutoff))
    .Add(Subqueries.Ne(EventType.LogOff, subquery));
```